# Swift Print function formatting

Tags: swift, string, printing, string-formatting

[This article](https://codeburst.io/swift-map-flatmap-filter-and-reduce-53959ebeb6aa) has this code here:

```
// flatMap
let flatCars = peopleArray.flatMap({ $0.cars })
print("Flatmap: \(flatCars)")
/*Result: Flatmap: ["i20", "Swift VXI", "Crita", "Swift VXI"]*/
```

What is going on in the print function. Why can it not just be this:

```
print("Flatmap: ", flatCars) //typed outside of IDE
```

Is `"Flatmap: \(flatCars)"` meant to be string formatting similar to javascript's template literals e.g `"Flatmap: ${flatCars}"` in Js?

Useful resources for better understanding would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is similar to ${} in javaScript, and it is called *String Interpolation*:

> String interpolation is a way to construct a new String value from a mix of constants, variables, literals, and expressions by including their values inside a string literal.

You can find more detailed information in here: [Swift Documentation](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/StringsAndCharacters.html)
under the section "String Interpolation".